# Make a Webpage Cacheable - Codeigniter Php Chrome Optimization

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, caching, optimization

Im observing a very high load time on my webpage and so i decided to run this Audit on chrome to detect areas where i can improve the speed

So chrome suggested that i

> The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making
>   them cacheable if possible:

and there are 76 file listed below that are image files , CSS , and PHP files

i want to know how do i make these file "cacheable"

Two more suggestion that are included are :

1. > There are multiple resources served from same domain. Consider
   >   combining them into as few files as possible.9 CSS resources served
   >   from localhost.
2. > There are multiple resources served from same domain. Consider
   >   combining them into as few files as possible.16 JavaScript resources
   >   served from localhost.

I wanted to know how much these 2 ^ properties will help me increase the speed of loading the site.

Please if possible do give me other options too , to make my website load faster apart from mentioned above.In dire need of help , the sites really slowed one and need to optimize the loading asap

Thank you

Comment: some one , any one ! please please

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html tried this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate and minify CSS and JS with CodeIgniter, use [Carabiner](http://getsparks.org/packages/carabiner/versions/HEAD/show).

As for caching resources, that task is usually best done by the webserver... Apache or NGINX or whatever you are running. You configure your webserver to send what's often referred to as a "far future expires header", and you can configure this by file type.

Comment: please can u elaborate on the caching part , please please please ?

Comment: It depends on your webserver... are you running Apache? NGINX? Lighttpd? etc.